# ArcMap - Display direction of points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, point, symbology, direction

I imported a few geotagged images and created a points shape showing their locations (or more accurately, the location of the camera) with the "Geotagged Photos to Points" tools. The attribute table contains a column called direction, which contains the direction the camera was facing. Is it possible to show that direction with arrow icons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this in two different ways, either rotating your symbology (mark each location with a symbol that points at ), or rotating a label (each location has a static point symbol, and label rotated). Here's the Esri help page for each method:

1. Rotate the label: [Setting label rotation using a numeric field.](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s800000037000000) I think this would work better for your particular case, since you can simply define the default symbol as an arrow and rotate accordingly.
2. Rotate the point symbol: [Rotating point feature symbols.](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s50000001v000000) This may be a better approach if not all of your points have an associated direction.

In either case, use the field `Direction` to get the amount of rotation to apply. Note that the direction values should be numerical (e.g. *45* not *northeast*) to work properly.

> The angle represents either geographic or arithmetic coordinates. Geographic rotates labels from north in a clockwise direction, while Arithmetic rotates labels from east in a counterclockwise direction.

Comment: I had a co-worker the other day who did this. She used the geographic angles with a field called angles. The results were arrows pointing in the opposite direction she wanted (don't know where she got the angles from). I had to select records where angle was >= 180 and subtract 180 in field calculator, and add 180 to records where angle was < 180. This worked for her. Just an FYI, in case you get similar results.

Comment: Just to add a little to @recurvata.  To really use the angles in a shapefile, you need to know which direction 0 degrees is and what kind of rotation (clockwise vs counter clockwise) was used.  It is also good to know the range (0-360 vs 0 -> 180 / 0 -> -180) of the degree values.  I spent a good chunk of time recently figuring out different rotations, etc.